# Error establishing a database connection for some files

Tags: database

Host: Blue Host

I have just moved a friends wordpress site to another host, something I have done a few time now without fault.

This time there is an issue with random files. The website loads fine but there is a problem loading various files like a custom css files and javascript files required for the site.

for example:

http://thewebsite.co.uk/wp-content/themes/ex/7league/css/customcss.php?color_profile&post&ver=4.2.4

fails to load. If i check the content of the folder it exists and I can edit it. but as soon as I open the file in a URL it gives the error message in the title.

The same happens to other js files and css files in the header.

I also can't load into the admin dashboard. with the same error. The rest of the site loads fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a file permission issue on the server. If the file is visible on the file system but not rendering properly in the browser it typically means:

1) The web server (apache, iis, nginx) can't see the file because it's assigned to the wrong owner:group or the permissions are set too restrictively on the file itself.

2) The web server can see it but is not sure how to properly process/respond to the request (for example a .php file but PHP isn't running on the server).

My guess is #1 since you said some of your pages work and others don't.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that the problem was caused by the SuperCache plugin.

There was definitely an issue with the database connection but the fact that the page was loading most of its content deceived me in thinking that it wasn't the problem.

- I disabled the SuperCache plugin
- Paired the db user to the database in cpanel
- Reset the password

Problem fixed